# When do we add the suffix -tter to a word?

Tags: suffixes

Normally we use this suffix for different words

Twitter
Flutter
Emitter
Chatter
Fitter

Is there anything that this suffix "-tter" is used to refer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the  erroneous belief that "tter" is recognized as a suffix.

Comment: Because ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎unicorns.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative

Answer (score 3):

The suffix is actually -er. Words ending in T often double the T in this case.

The meaning is "one who does" so a fitter is one who fits (things), etc.

Twit, emit, chat, and fit are the root words; flutter I'm not so sure about...

Comment: Only the _-er_ suffixes in _emitter_ and _fitter_ are examples of the derivational morpheme that makes agentive (_reader, leader, writer_) or instrumental (_opener, shredder, typewriter_) nouns. _Twitter, flutter,_ and _chatter_ are onomatopoeic words, not agentives.

Comment: I assume you don't twit. Perhaps you tweet.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twit) definition 1: "an act of twitting :  taunt"

Comment: I know what a [twit](http://youtu.be/TSqkdcT25ss) is. People on twitter tweet.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Perhaps you should go tweet that you just got twitted.

Comment: @JohnLawler Twitter and chatter may ALSO have onomatopoeic definitions, but a chatter is also one who chats and a twitter, one who twits.

Comment: Really? Having never twoten, I wouldn't know about _twitter_; but whereas _chatter_ is decomposable that way, I don't think I've ever heard it used. There's already special words for that, like _chatterbox_ and _chatty_.